# using sed to add quotes around few particular strings

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am having difficulty achieving this. I am trying manipulate the file contents with `SED` to induce quotes around few strings. 
can you please help?

file contents are :

```
/apps/as-agent -metaspace AlertsMS -discovery tcp://localhost:7877;localhost:7789 -listen tcp://localhost:7787 -input mySpace.txt
```

And I am expecting to SED to get the file contents as below with quotes around selected strings:

```
 /apps/as-agent -metaspace 'AlertsMS' -discovery 'tcp://localhost:7877;localhost:7789' -listen 'tcp://localhost:7787' -input 'mySpace.txt'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this awk one-liner does it:

```
awk -v q="'" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/^[^-]/)$i=q $i q}7' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sed "s/ \([^- ][^ ]*\)/ '\1'/g" file
```

Explanation:

- matches a space
- `[^- ]` matches any char but dash and space
- `[^ ]*` matches zero or more non-space chars
- `\(` and `\)` are to populate capture group 1 with the portion of input matching regexp between them, so we can use it in replacement string as `\1`

Comment: can you please elaborate this one?